# Timeline without extends Application?

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to use Timeline without extends Application?
I wrote a simple testClass, but it seems that Timline code dont run.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * .
 */
public class Time {

public static void main (String []args){
    Duration ka = new Duration(5);
    Timeline time = new Timeline( new KeyFrame(ka,k->{
        System.out.println("Timelineloop");

        //sendToAll(update);

    }));
     time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    time.play();
    System.out.println("hey");
}
}
```

EDIT CODE !!!
Now i am calling Time.start(), from an Application Class but still it donest work?

```
  import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
  import javafx.animation.Timeline;
  import javafx.util.Duration;

  /**
   * .
   */
public class Time extends Thread{

public static void run(){
Duration ka = new Duration(5);
Timeline time = new Timeline( new KeyFrame(ka,k->{
    System.out.println("Timelineloop");

    //sendToAll(update);

}));
 time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
time.play();
System.out.println("hey");
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updates to properties defined in `Timeline`s, and their event handlers, are executed on the FX Application Thread. Therefore you need the FX toolkit to have been started in order for them to work. You don't have to be in an `Application` subclass, but you do need FX to be running.

In the case you posted, you would just use a regular old [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: Thanks, i checked Timer and get a new idea, I edit my answer

Comment: In your updated code, the FX toolkit is still never started. It is started if you call `Application.launch()` or if you create a `JFXPanel` . I don't even see an `Application` class there, as you state.